How to replace a word in Java
I have an assignment in CodeHS for AP com sci A, but I don't understand the concept of string traversal.
A programmer has written a method called replaceLetter that counts the amount of times a letter is present in a word. Your job is to modify this existing method to fulfill a new purpose.
Rather than count the instances of a letter in a String, write a program that replaces all except the first instance of one letter with another. You should directly modify replaceLetter to get this program to work. In the starter code, replaceLetter only has two parameter values. Your new version should have a third parameter to indicate which String value is replacing the existing letter. Add that third parameter to the end of the parameter list in the method header.
For example,
replaceLetter("hello", "l", "y")
returns

"helyo"

Sample output:
Enter a word:
puppy
Enter the letter to be replaced: 
p
Enter the new letter: 
d

Result: puddy
Hint: The letters will be assigned from the user as String values. Make sure to use String methods to compare them!
I could only call the method in man, but I don't know what the next step would be.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Letter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Ask the user for 3 things: their word, letter they want to replace,
        // and replacing letter.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
        String letter = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the letter to be replaced: ");
        String replace = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new letter: ");
        String newLetter = input.nextLine();
        // Call the method replaceLetter and pass all 3 of these items to it for 
        // string processing.
        System.out.println(replaceLetter(letter, replace, newLetter));
    }
    
    // Modify this method so that it will take a third parameter from a user --
    // the String with which they want to replace letterToReplace 
    // 
    // This method should replace all BUT the first occurence of letterToReplace
    // You may find .indexOf to be useful, though there are several ways to solve this problem.
    // This method should return the modified String.
    public static int replaceLetter(String word, String letterToReplace, String newLetter)
    {
        
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(letterToReplace))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

How do I do this?

Did you read the javadocs for the String class.  Especially as hinted in the sample code, did you read up on .indexOf ?

Yes, but it still confuses me

It's a poorly written exercise: You wouldn't use code like that to do this new task. You would do something like remember where the first occurrence is using String#indexOf, divide the string into 2 parts before and after the first using String#substring, replace all in part 2 using String#replace, then glue them back together.

On a side note be careful with word.substring(i, i+1) etc. - Since the parameters are of type String the "letter" to replace etc. can be longer than 1 character since user input isn't limited. A very simple solution would involve substring(0,1) to "ignore" the first character and replace() to do the replacements. This might not be what you're meant to learn though so you might need to check (you might be required to use a loop, compare characters yourself etc.).

This question has actually been deleted once already

To check if the current index is the first occurrence of the letter, you can check if String#indexOf returns the same index since it returns the index of the first occurrence. Then you can easily append either the replacement if the current character is equal to the character to replace and this is not the index of its first occurrence or the current letter otherwise to a StringBuilder.
